# Spinner em conjunto

Tags: java, android

- Tenho um `Spinner` que é responsável pelos **Estados** do Brasil.
- E outro `Spinner` responsável pelas **Capitais** do Brasil.
- Preciso que quando for **selecionado** o **Estado** outro spinner de Cidades seja **desbloqueado** e mostre a sua respectiva Capital que corresponde ao seu Estado.

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, no entanto vou te mostrar uma jeito usando o método `setOnItemSelectedListener()`. Desta forma, verifico se o item selecionado é o primeiro usando `position == 0`. Na primeiro posição existe a frase `Escolha o Estado`. Se esta posição estiver selecionada, o `spinner` referente as Cidades permanecerá desativada usando `setEnabled(false)`. Veja abaixo:

**MainActivity.java**

***libs*:**

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
```

***code*:**

```
    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0)
                spinner2.setEnabled(false);
            else
                spinner2.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/estados"
    android:prompt="@string/estados_prompt" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/cidades"
    android:prompt="@string/cidades_prompt" />
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="estados_prompt">Escolha o estado</string>
<string-array name="estados">
    <item>Escolha o Estado</item>
    <item>São Paulo</item>
    <item>Rio De Janeiro</item>
    <item>Minas Gerais</item>
</string-array>

<string name="cidades_prompt">Escolha a cidade</string>
<string-array name="cidades">
    <item>Escolha a cidade</item>
    <item>Atibaia</item>
    <item>Petrópolis</item>
    <item>Belo Horizonte</item>
</string-array>
```

Obs.: Este é um exemplo bem simples, pois na prática o ideal seria filtrar a cidade de acordo com o Estado.

Para mais detalhes sobre `Spinner`'s, leia [a documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Nos paramentos -> parent e view informa: Cannot resolve symbol parent... Em setOnItemSelectedListener informa a mesma coisa também. E em AdapterView<?> informa -> 'Expression expected'

Comment: @Júnior não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: Parent, View, AdapterView<?>. Estão dando erro. Estou colocando esse código dentro do meu "activityMenu.java"

Comment: A sua orientação está igual ao que coloquei dentro do "strings.xml" e "activity_menu.xml".

Comment: @Júnior você importou as bibliotecas corretamente?

Comment: import android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.view.View; import android.widget.AdapterView; import android.widget.Spinner;

Comment: @Júnior aqui ta funcionando perfeitamente. Tente dar um clear no seu projeto.

Comment: @Júnior entendi porque ta errado. Você tem que inserir esse trecho dentro do seu onCreate.

Comment: Desculpa a vergonha...' Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para ativar/desativar uma view, use o metodo setEnabled().

```
Spinner capitais = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCapitais);
capitais.setEnabled(true) // para ativar a view
capitais.setEnabled(false) // para desativar a view
```

Comment: Eu coloquei o 'onClick' dentro do Layout quando eu  clico dá erro...

Comment: OnClick não é o evento mais indicado do caso do spinner, pois não se trata de ver se foi clicado, mas sim, se algo foi selecionado. Veja a resposta do Ack Lay,  está mais completa.

Comment: Rene, muito obrigado!