# Listar valores de um array em um spinner, e ao ser selecionado um item imprimir seu valor de outro array

Tags: android

Eu tenho um spinner que lista os tipos de pessoa (física e jurídica - Respectivamente IDs = 1 e 2) e gostaria de ao selecionar um deles, fosse impresso em um *Toast* seu *ID*.

```
//array tipoPessoa
private String[] tipoPessoa = new String[]{"física", "jurídica"};

//array idPessoa
private String[] tipoPessoaId = new String[]{"1", "2"};
```

O trecho de código a seguir é como eu consigo imprimir o *id* do item, porém eu quero imprimir o seu valor no *array* `tipoPessoaId` conforme sua *posição* em `tipoPessoa`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tipoPessoa);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_tipo_pessoa);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String idTipoPessoa = "O ID é: " + parent.getItemIdAtPosition((int) id);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), idTipoPessoa, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Quer que se for `fisica` imprima `1` porque é o elemento na mesma posição `0` do outro array, e `jurídica` imprima `2` pelo mesmo motivo ?

Comment: Isso mesmo Isac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O parâmetro `position` dá lhe a posição da `View` no `Adapter` e subsequentemente a posição do elemento escolhido no array passado ao `Adapter`.

Logo precisa apenas de aceder na mesma posição no outro array:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String idTipoPessoa = "O ID é: " + tipoPessoaId[position];//<---aqui
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), idTipoPessoa, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe outro tópico que também mostra uma forma de fazer isso, mas em outro contexto, o de spinners aninhados:

[Spinner em conjunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176740/spinner-em-conjunto)